# My App works perfectly on my Droid X, reviewers complain of crashes on other devices - how to debug?

Tags: android-emulator, android

Some say it doesnt start on their HTC Hero, another says it doesnt open in their Cliq, etc.  I built the entire app using my Droid X to debug.  Now that the app is released, and the code is interacting with so many different types of hardware, how do I figure out what may be going wrong for these users?

In my Crash errors log I have one record of a crash, and I believe I've already fixed this.  It was certainly not responsible for the crashes that users are complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to check manually or maybe it's a problem of multiresolution because different mobile have different resolutions. Otherwise if it is possible then you have to include crash log report in your application which send crash logs to your email id.

Or you can ask them to install crash log reporter and set your emailid to target for crash report. Try this link, first one for manually adding code to your application.

https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/log-collector_tlt.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Logcat outputs in release mode? May be they help you out..

Alternatively, you can test it out on 3rd party mobile testing vendors.. Where in you can buy some hours and do some quick testing...

Comment: How would I review a Logcat output in release mode?